Issues with printing text using INT 21h, 40h with MASM
So, i'm writing a basic program in assembly that prints the contents of a file that is written on the command-line arguments, it went smoothly up until i needed to print the file's contents.
I decided to use INT 21h, 40h instead of INT 21h, 09h to print the text, because it is a safer option and should theoretically work...plus i already tried it and it didn't work. However..it doesn't print anything to screen, at all.
And it's not the interrupt's problem, i tried in a seperate file printing Hello World using it and it worked like a charm.
Alongside that, i also tried INT 21h, 01h to print the first character...but it just printed the letter 'r'.
This is the code i wrote, alongside the file i've tried this on :
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 50h

READnWRITE equ 02
SEEK_END equ 02

.DATA
  argv db 80h dup(0)
  file_handle dw ?
  file_size dw ?
  file_segment dw ?

.CODE

main PROC
  mov ax, @DATA
  mov ds, ax

  mov si, 82h
  lea di, [argv]

  ;Copy the command-line arguments to argv.

mem_cpy:
  mov al, es:[si]
  cmp al, 0Dh           ;The command-line arguments end with a carriage-return (0Dh).
  je done
  mov ds:[di], al
  inc si
  inc di
  jmp mem_cpy

done:

  ;Open null-terminated file using INT 21h, 3Dh.

  mov ah, 03Dh
  mov al, READnWRITE
  lea dx, argv
  int 21h
  mov [file_handle], ax
  mov bx, ax

  ;Get file size by going to EOF and getting the offset using INT 21h, 42h.

  mov ah, 042h
  mov al, SEEK_END
  xor dx, dx
  int 21h
  mov [file_size], ax

  ;Go back to the beggining of the file.

  mov ah, 042h
  xor al, al
  int 21h

  ;Convert the file size from bytes to paragraphs (1 paragraph = 16 bytes).

  mov bx, [file_size]
  add bx, 15
  mov cl, 4
  shr bx, cl

  ;Allocate enough paragraphs for the file's contents using INT 21h, 48h.

  mov ah, 48h
  int 21h
  mov [file_segment], ax

  ;Read the file's contents and write it into the allocated space.

  mov ah, 03Fh
  mov bx, [file_handle]
  mov cx, [file_size]

  push ds

  mov ds, [file_segment]
  int 21h
  
  ;Write the file's contents to the screen (well..that's what it's supposed to do-).

  mov ah, 040h
  mov bx, 1
  int 21h

  pop ds

  ;Terminate.

  mov ax, 4C00h
  int 21h
main ENDP
END main

Do what you want 'cause a pirate is free
You are a pirate!

Another note, when i ran the program with Turbo Debugger, AX gets set to the file size after INT 21h, 40h gets run, which means that the text has been printed successfully...which is weird.
By the way, this is what i used as a reference : https://www.stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html
Thanks! :D

Two problems: You didn't shrink the process's memory block so allocating memory may fail. And the int 21h function 42h calls take a seek offset in cx:dx as input, which you didn't properly set up.

You also didn't set up dx for the int 21h function 3Fh and 40h calls.

The first is not an issue if the exe header is filled properly. cx should definitely be zeroed for the seek, yes. Although since the file size is reportedly correct that does not seem to be the problem. The third happens to work if the file is less than 64k in size which is the case here. Still should be fixed of course.

Zeroing cx makes it work here.

@ecm sorry, i forgot to free the allocated space, my bad...about int 21h function 42h, i cleared cx and it works!! i don't know why it works now, CX is set to 0 when the program starts (well, thats what turbo debugger tells me), and about function 3Fh and 40h, DX is already set to zero when i use function 42h, so theres no need to reset it to zero. Thank you!!

cx is not guaranteed to be zero. That happens to be true when running under the debugger and in that case the original program even works.
